# Using pdfium.lib with GCC in a very simple program

Tags: gcc, lib, pdfium

I am trying to add pdfium.lib library in a small program in windows. The program is...

```
    #include <fpdfview.h>

int main() {
  FPDF_LIBRARY_CONFIG config;
  config.version = 2;
  config.m_pUserFontPaths = NULL;
  config.m_pIsolate = NULL;
  config.m_v8EmbedderSlot = 0;

  FPDF_InitLibraryWithConfig(&config);

  FPDF_DestroyLibrary();
  return 0;
}
```

Pdfium.lib has build as complete lib and runs ok in Linux.(pdf_is_complete_lib = true).

When linking in GCC with the "-pg -s -Wl,--start-group pdfium.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread" parameters works fine in Linux.

But in Windows10 with "-pg -s -Wl,--start-group pdfium.lib -Wl,--end-group -lpthread" parameters. Program say "main.cpp|7|undefined reference to `FPDF_InitLibrary'|, .... ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
I am stack here in very simple program with main, because i am new to libs, so i need help.
I have also post the problem to google pdfium mailing list.
Thank you
Jim

But in windows i